# How to use if... in Spring Controller

Tags: spring

Im trying to make a function that inserts 0 into DB when 'Time' value is 0 or null. (In Spring Controller)

This is what I did.

```
if(result.getTime() == null || "")  {
result.setTime("0");
}
```

But I keep getting an error. Is that even a right method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
if(result.getTime() == null || result.getTime().equals("")) {
    result.setTime("0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this safely.

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(result.getTime())) {
    result.setTime("0");
}
```

Refer this [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) for more info.